# Pulling links to all documents that have a column "XXXX" in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a site collection in which there are lot of sites, and each site has a number of documents which are tagged as "XXX" in a particular column. Now, if I have to pull links to all documents in the site collection that are tagged "XXX" and display them in a list, how do I go about it? I mean how do I start it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any knowledge with JavaScript ? Because you could use it to do this kind of task...

For example with [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetAllSubWebCollection) you can get all the sites:

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("Webs > Web").each(function() {
      var $node = $(this);
      getDocuments( $node.attr("Title") );
    });
  }
});
```

Then with [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.lists) (because the syntax is easier but you can still use SPServices) you can get the documents:

```
function getDocuments(site) {
  $SP().list("My Document List", site).get({fields:"Title",where:"My_x0020_Column = 'XXX'"}, function(data) {
    for (var i=data.length; i--;) console.log(data[i].getAttribute("Title"))
  })
}
```

Of course at this point, instead of `console.log` you should inject the link into your webpage.
It's just a very basic example of what you could do.